# reporting location of variably-nested XML data

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I am attempting to parse an XML file trying to find a particular value. Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dump>
 <folder id="A0">
  <folder id="A1">
   <setting id="setting0">
    <sequence id="sequence0">
     <group name="info">
      <variable name="foo" value="15"/>
     </group>
    </sequence>
   </setting>
  </folder>
 </folder>
</dump>
```

Data::Dumper produces

```
$VAR1 = {
          'folder' => {
                      'id' => 'A0',
                      'folder' => {
                                  'setting' => {
                                               'sequence' => {
                                                             'group' => {
                                                                        'variable' => {
                                                                                      'value' => '15',
                                                                                      'name' => 'foo'
                                                                                    },
                                                                        'name' => 'info'
                                                                      },
                                                             'id' => 'sequence0'
                                                           },
                                               'id' => 'setting0'
                                             },
                                  'id' => 'A1'
                                }
                    }
        };
```

My goal is a report which says something like: "foo has a value of 15 at A0/A1/setting0/sequence0". Notice I want to use the `id`s to refer to the "breadcrumb" trail to the location of `foo`.

Currently I access the value "15" in this example XML with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml -> XMLin('test1.xml');
print $data -> {folder}{folder}{setting}{sequence}{group}{variable}{value};
```

(However this doesn't work if there is more than one `<variable>`, and there will be...but that's not my main challenge...)

The problem is the XML will contain an unpredictable nesting of `<folder>`s, and I don't know how to find where a `<variable>` exists with `name="foo"`, because I don't know how deep it will be.
Multiple instances of `foo` will occur, but just one for each `sequence`.

A last little kicker is that I have access to XML::Simple and XML::Parser only! No SAX/Twig/LibXML etc. And the XML data file may be up to 100MB in size.

All that now sounds quite complicated so I shall re-state my goal: traverse the XML for wherever `<variable>` exists with `name="foo"` and report its `value` and location in the tree. Thanks for any help with this.

---

**Edit:** using mirod's method below, here's what worked:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Twig;

my $twig = new XML::Twig( 
                twig_handlers =>
                   { 'variable[@name="foo"]' => \&variable,
                     group => sub { $_->purge; }  }
                        );
$twig->parsefile( "test.xml");

sub variable
  { my( $t, $var)= @_;
    my $location= join '/', grep { $_ } map { $_->id } reverse $var->ancestors;
    print $var->att( 'name'), " has value ", $var->att( 'value'), " at $location\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't install XML::Twig? It's a pure Perl module (which depends on XML::Parser, which you have installed), so you can always copy the file `Twig.pm` from the distribution as `myTwig.pm` in your code directory, `use myTwig;` and voilà.

Then the code is pretty simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use myTwig;


XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'variable[@name="foo"]' => \&variable,
                                   # next line if you need to reduce memory footprint
                                   group => sub { $_->purge; }, 
                                 }
         ->parse( \*DATA); # replace with parsefile( 'my.xml') for the real data

sub variable
  { my( $t, $var)= @_;
    my $location= join '/', grep { $_ } map { $_->id } reverse $var->ancestors;
    print $var->att( 'name'), " has value ", $var->att( 'value'), " at $location\n";
  }

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dump>
 <folder id="A0">
  <folder id="A1">
   <setting id="setting0">
    <sequence id="sequence0">
     <group name="info">
      <variable name="foo" value="15"/>
     </group>
    </sequence>
   </setting>
  </folder>
 </folder>
</dump>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You've persuaded me that installation of XML::Twig is so simple that it's worth doing (simply putting Twig.pm in the right directory, as you say). I was reluctant to install anything new because the solution is to be applied in already-distributed VMs, so I was looking for simplicity in instructions for end users. I got a syntax error `near "->parse"` with the above code so I'll post my minor adjustments in an edit.

Comment: oops, cut'n paste error! I had an extra comma before the `parse`. Fixed now.